# How to use the output of select statement to use as a condition in another select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to use the output of select statement to use as a condition in another select. 
For example:

```
Select uid from info where id = 1;
```

Output

```
|uid|
| 3 |
```

-- i will use the output of this on the other query which is in dynamic manner.

```
Select uid from info where id = 3
```

*the query will stop if there is no any id found.
Can you help me to find best practice  for it?

Comment: if there is no data means it wont show you any result for the code purpose you need to write the conditions...

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this or are we your first port of call?

Comment: `SELECT uid FROM info WHERE id = (SELECT uid FROM info WHERE id = 1)`

Comment: what if i get another id which is i will use it again on another select statement. It will only stop if there is no row to return.